# Can the Mailchimp module email node content?

Tags: 7, emails

I have a blog page. I want to add a sign-up box to collect email addresses so I can email everyone when a new blog entry is added. As I'm on shared hosting, I believe there is less chance of them getting marked as spam if I use a service such as Mailchimp to send the emails.

The Mailchimp module has a signup form. However, as far as I can tell, I can only send email through the Mailchimp 'campaigns' feature and not arbitrary Drupal node content.

Does anyone know if there is a way for the Mailchimp module to email node content or node links?

Comment: Do you have full control over your hosting environment (eg, VPN w/ root access) ?

Comment: @mpdonadio No afraid not. Just basic cPanel access. UKHost4u.com